# I get org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException which get resolved after restarting server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

The problem here is that the same request works fine after restarting the server.

This is the stackTrace error
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

This is the request Handler

```
@PostMapping("/buy-data")
@ApiOperation(value = "Guest buy data")
public ResponseEntity<?> buyData(@Valid @RequestBody BuyDataPaymentDto 
paymentDto, Errors errors,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "web") String channel) 
{
   ...
}
```

This is the BuyDataPaymentDto

```
public class BuyDataPaymentDto {

    private long productId;
    private String transactionId;
    private String status;
    private long paymentId;
    private String cardLast4Digit;
    private long networkId;
    private String transactionRef;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Receiver's msisdn cannot be blank")
    private String receiverMsisdn;

    public BuyDataPaymentDto() {
    }

    public long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public long getPaymentId() {
        return paymentId;
    }

    public void setPaymentId(long paymentId) {
        this.paymentId = paymentId;
    }

    public String getCardLast4Digit() {
        return cardLast4Digit;
    }

    public void setCardLast4Digit(String cardLast4Digit) {
        this.cardLast4Digit = cardLast4Digit;
    }

    public long getNetworkId() {
        return networkId;
    }

    public void setNetworkId(long networkId) {
        this.networkId = networkId;
    }

    public String getTransactionRef() {
        return transactionRef;
    }

    public void setTransactionRef(String transactionRef) {
        this.transactionRef = transactionRef;
    }

    public String getReceiverMsisdn() {
        return receiverMsisdn;
    }

    public void setReceiverMsisdn(String receiverMsisdn) {
        this.receiverMsisdn = receiverMsisdn;
    }
}
```